# Selenium filling form information python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape from the following website:
https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/rechJuriJudi.do?reprise=true&page=1

I am only interested in a specific subset of the results it can present so I want to use Selenium to fill in a search query.

To be more specific there are 2 parts I am interest in:

```
  <select name="champJuridictions" id="champ1" class="textarea"><option value="" class="optionPaire">-- Toutes les juridictions --</option>
  <option value="cour de cassation" selected="selected" class="optionImpaire">Cour de cassation</option>
  <option value="juridiction d'appel" class="optionPaire">Juridictions d'appel</option>
  <option value="juridictions du premier degre" class="optionImpaire">Juridictions du premier degré</option>
  <option value="tribunal des conflits" class="optionPaire">Tribunal des conflits</option></select>
```

Which is a dropdown window, where I want to pick one of the options (the first one).

The other is an open field which I have to fill with a word.

```
<span class="inputCode">
                        <input type="text" name="champMotsRecherches1" value="" id="champ7" class="textarea">
                    </span>
```

Where value should be equal to "Impôt".

How would I fill such a query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a text box, you can use the Selenium `find_element_by_id` method and then use the `send_keys` method on that element to send whatever input you wish.

```
browser.find_element_by_id("my_id").send_keys("my_text")
```

For a dropdown menu, you can use either `select_by_index` or `select_by_visible_text`.

```
menu = browser.find_element_by_id("my_dropdown_menu")
menu.select_by_index(index)
menu.select_by_visible_text("text")
```

Additional Resources:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

http://thiagomarzagao.com/2013/11/12/webscraping-with-selenium-part-1/

Comment: Thank you, it seems my original search for the answer was not thorough enough. Thanks for pointing me to it :)

Comment: No problem!  If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.  :)