# how to select the drop down option in webpage using selenium python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to select the drop down option in the webpage using python selenium webdriver

Pasted the HTML code of those web elements,

```html
<td class="CR">
   <select onchange="wl_recalc();" name="wl_nmode">
   <option value="-1">Auto</option>
   <option value="0">Off</option>
   </select>
</td>
```

This is the image of the dropdown option which i am not able to select, i am able to click the 802.11n mode as shown in the picture by finding element by name. but i am unuccessfull in setting the option to off by selecting the element using xpath

[image]

Comment: able to click with below command
browser.find_element_by_name("wl_nmode").click()
not able to select option off & set it using below command
browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/form[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/select/option[2]").click()

Comment: can you please put your python code into your question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43521600/selenium-filling-form-information-python, same question essentially. Should provide a solution.